# Dynamically Relocate a Formula Associated with a Dynamic Range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

I am trying to help a colleague with an enhancement to a spreadsheet.  We are using Excel 365.

In cell **C3** we have the formula:

```
=FILTER(O1:O51,O1:O51>E1)
```

It produces a dynamic column of results that will grow or shrink depending on the value in **E1**.  In **C1** we have a formula that sums the cells below:

```
=SUM(C3#)
```

[image]

All this works.

My colleague wants to put the formula at the bottom of the dynamic spill-down.  He also wants the formula to automatically move up or down as the spill-down grows or shrinks.  So in the illustration, the formula would go in cell **C20**.

I have no idea how to do this or even if it is possible.

My suggestion was to not include the formula.  First set the filter parameter and then run this short macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range, rNext As Range
    Set r = Range("C3#")
    Set rNext = r(r.Count + 1)
    
    rNext.Formula = "=SUM(C3#)"
End Sub
```

The macro will put the formula in the correct cell.  Colleague responded "not automatic enough"

Any suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: can you link it to a worksheet_caclulate event?

Comment: @ScottCraner interesting idea....the macro would need to remove previous formula if there was one; allow the spill to occur; then insert the formula in its new place......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a formula:

```
=LET(filt,FILTER(O1:O51,O1:O51>E1),CHOOSE(INT(SEQUENCE(COUNT(filt)+1,,0)/COUNT(filt))+1,filt,SUM(filt)))
```

`INT(SEQUENCE(COUNT(filt)+1,,0)/COUNT(filt))+1` returns an array of `1`s the count of the numbers returned by the FILTER and append a 2 to the end.  Then with CHOOSE we return first each number in the FILTER then the `2` returns the SUM.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! .................................This is **BEAUTIFUL**

Comment: Thank you.  Now, go take credit for it and wow your co-worker with your knowledge.

Comment: No way....I will show him your Post....I am trying to train him to use the Forum...